# Form can not be edited using Fabrik in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Can you help me I am trying to edit a listbox in a form using a component fabrik but it fails to allow me to edit components and displays the following error

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/theminin/public_html/administrator/components/com_fabrik/models/lists.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/theminin/public_html/libraries/legacy/model/legacy.php on line
>   184
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/theminin/public_html/administrator/components/com_fabrik/models/lists.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/theminin/public_html/libraries/legacy/model/legacy.php on line
>   18

Can you help with suggestion cause i tried to reinstall fabrik it did not work.

Comment: Wich Versions are you using?

Comment: Hi  Facundo Lafuente Diaz,thanks for replying the version of joomla is Joomla! 3.3.6 ,PHP version is 5.5.35,the Fabrik is 3.5(which i don't think it is the problem because i reinstalled but still